# Convert Pandas DataFrame from matrix to flat table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

[image: df1]

I would like this to convert to a flat table as below

[image: df2]

Comment: Is the dataframe multi-indexed? Also what is the expected data type for the output?

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index()` this would work for your case

Comment: no. its not multi indexed. Even the first two columns got headers. I am expecting the solution in a data frame, which i would like to export to an excel sheet

Comment: Naga Kiran's solution worked like a charm. thanks a lot

Comment: I would add it to answer, please close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pd.DataFrame.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), which could list all dataframe values to a list

```
df.stack().reset_index()
```

Out:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) does the trick?

Or to keep the index use [pandas.DataFrame.to_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html#pandas-dataframe-to-records)